# Looking for Code on UINavigational Controller to avoid 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, xcode5

Below is an error getting requesting for code on UINavigationalController

```
2013-11-02 09:30:33.727 NavigationalCntrlApp[465:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bd8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   UIKit                               0x003676bd __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke + 0
        3   UIKit                               0x003670b5 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 325
        4   UIKit                               0x003557d7 -[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:] + 122
        5   NavigationalCntrlApp                0x00002c91 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 673
        6   UIKit                               0x00225355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
        7   UIKit                               0x00225b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
        8   UIKit                               0x0022a3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
        9   UIKit                               0x0023e87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
        10  UIKit                               0x0023ede9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
        11  UIKit                               0x0022c025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
        12  GraphicsServices                    0x036e12f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
        13  GraphicsServices                    0x036e0e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x016b5d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x016b5a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x016e077c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x016dfac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x016df8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        19  UIKit                               0x00229add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
        20  UIKit                               0x0022bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        21  NavigationalCntrlApp                0x0000304d main + 141
        22  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7870d start + 1
        23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Can anyone help me why this error is getting, the same code is worked in Xcode 4.3, but it throwing error in Xcode 5.

Comment: Perhaps some code. If you read the error its related to how you are pushing your view controller.

Comment: I am new to iOS coding and learning self, could you please share code for UINavagationController,

Comment: Below is code I am using
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *tablecell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tablecell"];
    
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        tablecell.textLabel.text = [tablelist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 100, 70)];
        [tablecell addSubview:imageview];
    }

Comment: else
    {
        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(180, 5, 100, 30);
        [btn setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tablecell addSubview:btn];
    }
    
    return tablecell;
}

Comment: ok can you edit the question with your above code...

Comment: i have updated as u mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying set a navigationController as rootviewcontroller of a navigationController. That's not allowed

If I'm correct, you're doing this:

```
// 1. Make new UIViewController
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
// 2. Make UINavigationController
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
// 3. Set navigationController as rootViewController of a new navigationController
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];
```

While you should do this:

```
// 1. Make New UIViewController
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
// 2. Set it as rootviewcontroller of a new navigationController
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nav];
```

If I was wrong on your problem, please post some extra code in your question.